# Update View positions after TransitionManager.go(Scene,Transition)

Tags: android, animation

I was creating animation between 2 Scenes using `TransitionManager.go(Scene,Transition)` and everything worked just fine but after the animation finished I was no longer capable of clicking on the button which was moved from the center of the screen to the left side.

Looking around the Internet I found that this animation actually doesn't even move the `View`s, just animates them so I have to update their positions to new ones.

Isn't there any better way to do this than manually `.setLayoutParams` for all the `View`s in the `Scene`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that my Views actually were in the right positions after the animation but I had to reset my `OnClickListener`s every time `Scenes` changed

```
Transition.TransitionListener listener = new Transition.TransitionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
        //get view references from the new Scene and
        //reassign on click listeners to them 
    }
}
```

I just assigned this `listener` to my `Transition` and everything worked fine.

[Here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/building-animations-android-transition-framework-part-2/) is the post that helped me see my mistake.

Comment: link is unfortunately broken.. Do you think you can find the post you were referring to?